# Installer for an IE add-on and automated prerequisite installs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, add-in, installshield

I have a project that was given to me where, organically, they created it using Add-In Express and Visual studio. The issue they ran into is that some of the prerequisites needed to be installed before the actual add-in could be installed. So there is a 2 step process. I have some experience with InstallShield and believe my version is 2009. I am wondering if that will handle the install better than add-in express or if I should create a manual package in VS2010. Also, is there a way to silently install the prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

As a regular .net based application your Add-in Express based solution relies on the .net framework. So, .net framework should be installed on the end user PCs. Your solution may also include a lot of references or dependencies (if any) that should be installed before running the add-in installer.

You may be interested in the [Video: Fully featured setup projects for Office solutions](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/05/26/deployment-fully-featured-setup-video/) article on our technical blog.